# Extra directory entries in clearcase dynamic view on linux

Tags: linux, clearcase, dynamic-view

Why do I see all of the root file system directories in the root of my dynamic view? For example, when I `ls` at `/view/myview` I see `bin`, `boot`, `dev`, `etc`, `home`, `lib` and everything else that usually resides in `/`.
I can ignore those entries and change directory into a VOB and everything else is where I expect it. I've been using clearcase in Windows for years. I'm used to only seeing mounted VOBs in the root of my dynamic view.

I know the VOBs are also visible at `/` and the `setview` command will set a specific view into the root VOB entries.

Is there some option that can I turn off/on to remove these 'extra' entries?
Are they there for a good reason?
Is this just how MVFS works on linux?

**EDIT:**

I'm using clearcase 9.0.0.2 on CentOS 7.2.

Comment: What ClearCase version are you using? On which OS version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These "extra" directories are needed to support the cleartool setview command. This command "roots" a new shell in the view root. If these "mirrors" of the various "actual" root directory entries were not present, you would not be able to perform pretty much any operations that were not a compiled-in part of your current shell.

They cannot be disabled, as that would essentially render the setview operation useless.

Answer (score 0):

> Are they there for a good reason? Is this just how MVFS works on linux?

Apparently so.
See "[About the `/view` view root directory which is located in the root partition of a ClearCase server](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21270755)"

> ### Recommendations and precautions
>
> NEVER perform a recursive removal of `/view` while ClearCase is running because it will result in severe data loss caused because by what was described in the point above.
>
> **Since `/view/<viewname>` contains the entire root filesystem**, recursive removal starting at `/view` will act upon all files from `/` down -- even non-ClearCase files -- causing many to be removed. This is especially true if the recursive directory removal is performed by the root user, causing very dire results.
>
> If you should ever need to remove the `/view` directory mountpoint, you must ensure that ClearCase is stopped completely.
> Also, do not perform a recursive removal, instead only remove the directory mountpoint itself.

And:

> Is there some option that can I turn off/on to remove these 'extra' entries?

I never tried but try and add a selection rule at the end of your config spec like:

```
element bin -none
element etc -none
...
```

Just to see if that influence at all the view root folder content.